# Apache 404 error redirecting one site's error page for all other sites also

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu-12.04

I have 3 wordpress sites in my machine(in localhost) named site1, site2, site3. Whenever there is page not found it is being redirected to the site1's 404 error page instead of redirecting to their respective 404 pages. may be I set the apache's default error page somewhere. could anybody help me in this regard.

how to reset it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the `.htaccess` file in the root of your site, I think in there a line should say something similar with `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html`

try commenting out that line with a `#` and refresh

Comment: could you please let me know where does that file located,

Comment: in the root of your site, where the index page is

Comment: IT is not there, shall i create a new one by adding a line that u have specified

Comment: It is redirecting whenever i type something after the ip address like 192.168.0.122/aa or 192.168.0.122/aa etc to the same site's error page, its not about individual site, I think I did a mistake for whole apache server, is there any such chance

Comment: could you give me some more info first about how the directories are set up? You could always try adding it in the root of site2 with the correct url

Comment: so you DO have a `.htaccess` file? is there a `ModRewrite` in it? that could give you the wrong direction

Comment: there is no .htaccess file in my root folder (actually it was developed by somebody else, now I got it t make it work)

Comment: in `/wp-content/themes/default/404.php` WordPress saves the 404, maybe the 404 page of site2 does not exist?